# Connection issue with postgres and pg8000 python - clear password issue?

Tags: python, postgresql, pg8000

I'm trying to connect using:

```
conn = DBAPI.connect(host='sql2', user='XXX', password='XX', database='XX', socket_timeout=100, port=100)
```

I now find I get the following error:

```
pg8000.errors.InterfaceError: Authentication method 3 not supported by pg8000.
```

Looking around I get what this may mean:

```
 3 = Cleartext pwd (not supported by pg8000)
```

Are there any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (1.9.14) of pg8000 [supports password authentication](https://pythonhosted.org/pg8000/release_notes.html#version-1-9-14-2014-08-02).